# Creating a particular type of diagram

Tags: beamer, diagrams, matrices, sharelatex

This question is a follow on from [Diagrams in subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484020/diagrams-in-subequations)

I am trying to produce diagrams like those in the picture below. In particular, the top part of this style of diagram (above the word "everyone") I have tried to reproduce. I came up with this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
    \usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usetheme{Madrid} 
    \usepackage{empheq}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

\[
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      A & B\\
      \hline
      A & B\\
      \hline
       C 
    \end{array}
    \right)
  \]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, as you can see, the letter C does not occur below the vertical line, and the vertical line extends too far. How can I rectify this?[image: Example]

---

Edit:

In response to comments below, I would say first that my question is worth asking, since the format of the particular diagrams I was asking about are somewhat different from the format of the diagrams  in [Using multicolumn in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131867/using-multicolumn-in-latex). Moreover, it is not transparent for a beginner user of Latex, how one might adapt the information in that question to produce diagrams of the form I wish to produce.

In any case, even if that question is relevant to my question, I still have an additional problem, not mentioned in [Using multicolumn in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131867/using-mulmade) below to my question. This was the suggestion that I use \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}. Doing this I managed to produce:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
    \usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx,     amsfonts, braket}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usetheme{Madrid} 
    \usepackage{empheq}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

  \[
    \begin{array}{clc}
 A & B\\
  \hline
  A & B\\
  \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, note that the vertical line of the diagram disappears. How can I insert the vertical line?

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{C}`.

Comment: Also, load `array` and add something like  `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`.

Comment: @JouleV I have edited my question. It contains a problem brought out by trying to implement a suggestion here, and so is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Bernard I have tried a way of implementing what you suggested, and have edited my question to mention a problem I encountered doing so.

Comment: @user65526 You did it wrong. It is not `clc` but `c|c`.